# SQL join one column to many based on condition

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows:

Table A

```
Docnumber  Line  Amount Doctype

1000        1      100     3
1000        2      200     3
1001        1      300     5
```

Table B

```
Docnumber   Debit  Credit  Account

1000        100     0       5410
1000        200     0       5560
1001         0      300     6790
```

I'm trying to create a select which looks like this:

```
Docnumber  Line  Amount Account
1000        1     100     5410
1000        2     200     5560
1001        1     300     6790
```

So, logically, I'm trying to figure out a way to join *A.Amount to B.Debit where A.Doctype = 3 and join A.Amount to B.Credit where A.Doctype = 5*

As you can see, I'm a novice but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What  is your db engine?

Comment: Do you have any intermediate table which links docnumber with doctype?

Comment: @Mihai:  Table A links Docnumber with Doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server.  Also assuming that `Docnumber` is intended to play a role in your `JOIN` as well, despite not being explicitly stated in the question.

You can use any conditions on the `JOIN` that you want:

```
SELECT A.Docnumber, A.Line, A.Amount, B.Account
FROM A JOIN B
    ON A.Docnumber = B.Docnumber
       AND ((A.Doctype = 3 AND A.Amount = B.Debit)
            OR (A.Doctype = 5 AND A.Amount = B.Credit))
ORDER BY A.Docnumber, A.Line;
```

Alternatively, you could put it into the `WHERE` clause, which is probably more clear:

```
SELECT A.Docnumber, A.Line, A.Amount, B.Account
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Docnumber = B.Docnumber
WHERE (A.Doctype = 3 AND A.Amount = B.Debit) OR (A.Doctype = 5 AND A.Amount = B.Credit)
ORDER BY A.Docnumber, A.Line
```

Comment: @user3446436:  No problem.  If you found that my answer solved your issue, please mark the check by it to mark it as the answer.

Comment: the answers came in so fast that now you've set a baseline expectation for responsiveness.....which means I'll be back

Answer (score 1):

Actually easier than you might think!

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON (A.Doctype = 3 AND B.Debit = A.Amount) 
  OR (A.Doctype = 5 AND B.Credit= A.Amount)
```